# JavaFX graphics: How to change Paint settings?

Tags: java, javafx

Nearly a month ago I was testing JavaFX graphics API, however I was worried about performance. The performance problem is that I had to pass a `Paint` object for colorizing shapes.

---

#### Issue: it's impossible to change settings of an existing `Paint`

I just need to update a `Paint`, for example, `Color`, but there are no methods like `Color#setRed`, `Color#setGreen`, `Color#setBlue` and `Color#setOpacity`. There are no fields, too ([javafx.scene.paint.Color](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html)).

---

#### Performance

The unique way I can try to change settings of a `Paint` is to construct another `Paint` instead, however this will involve on running the garbage collector. Is that correct?

The compiler should optimize these objects automatically depending on how they're entirely used. But Oracle said nothing about that on its compiler, at least for me, so far.

If they say garbage collection is good, the fault isn't mine. I didn't mention anything about garbage collection being helpful.

---

So is it a good solution to re-construct a `Paint`? Do you guys also know of JavaFX alternatives that handle what I want?

Comment: *The unique way I can try to change settings of a Paint is to construct another Paint instead, however this will involve on running the garbage collector. Is that correct?* No. The paint could be referenced in some other place and thus not be eligible for garbage collection. Furthermore even if there no longer is a reference to an object this does not mean that "destroying" the last reference involves running the garbage collector. Usually garbage collection based on some other criteria.

Comment: You are creating problems that don't exist. Just create the new `Paint` instance as and when you need it. The memory footprint of an object that has four floating point values as its state is very small, and the GC is highly efficient at working with objects like this. Write the code you need to cleanly implement your requirements, and *if* you encounter performance problems, profile it and determine what causes them. Don't invent issues that don't exist.

Comment: @James_D I'm not inventing issues. If they say a single garbage collector run is slow, then imagine if that happens 5 times quickly?

Comment: But the garbage collector simply doesn't work like that. [Edit] your question and include the actual evidence you have that creating new `Paint` instances causes a performance problem. (If you have no such evidence, then you are inventing issues that don't exist.)

Comment: @James_D The code I had was a test. I only write real code when I know I've everything I need. For example, g++ and accurate libraries, but that's not the case... as of now. Not easily. Even because my internet is bad to download sure thing.

Comment: *" is it a good solution to re-construct a Paint?"*. Yes. It's the only solution, and it won't cause any performance problems.

Comment: @James_D What does confirm it won't cause any performance problems? Any specification made, about that, by Oracle? They basically say objects are garbage-collected. Zzz...

Comment: @James_D But I don't want the garbage collector to run. Not worried about anything you've said. I simply don't want to create new objects, if they interfer on running the gargabe collector. I've wrote many lexers for nothing; I won't write Java for nothing too.

Comment: @James_D No, I said about on what I want to do. It may run the garbage collector from other causes, but not from the cause of change settings of a single `Paint`. Not really worried.

Comment: @James_D I'm choosing Oracle's `javac` and Java Runtime Environment and etc., because it's easier than waiting for 2 years of my internet downloading `cl.exe` to easily compile C++ libraries or trying to setup gtkmm, which isn't getting anytime fine in here.

Comment: @James_D Deferenced? What you said doesn't make single sense for me. I couldn't deference anything... On C++, fine! When it's defaultly overloaded on pointers. And I'm mostly experienced on ECMAScript 4 too, but hate ECMAScript entirely now as it's hard to see a good compiler optimizing it and property gets/puts by internal offsets.

Comment: So, @James_D, you need to learn that not every compiler is like the other, an implementation isn't like the other too, depending on. There are guys that don't care for optimizations in general. Lua Official implementation not optimized on field accesses, for example. Same for LuaJ. With LuaJIT they don't optimize it at all, while it'd be possible. Me myself would implement a compiler, problem is that I have to write many lexers and restart them, just to build a parser manually, and so on.

Comment: @James_D "Deferenced" at all, but did anything or documentation say it got deleted? E.g., extra optimizations.

Comment: @James_D The compilers as well as the run time can optimize it. But at run time this would be too inefficient, I say, at the same time the code somehow runs.

Comment: @James_D There's good evidence. Zzz... It'll be an overhead for the run time, while it could be purely solved at compile time.

Comment: @James_D I think you don't know about static optimizations...

Comment: @James_D But I want to build a game. It'll be bad to run gc just bcuz of these unnecessary objects...

Comment: No choice other than quitting JavaSE or JavaFX. Unfortunately

Comment: @James_D About 2): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#setColor(java.awt.Color) It won't be enough to use `Canvas` or `Graphics`. I'll still need to use a `Color` instance for filling and stroking.

Comment: **Comments are not for extended discussion.** Remember that "you don't need to worry about this because…" is a valid answer, and should be posted into the answer box below, not left as a series of comments.

Comment: @James_D Interesting... Well, I couldn't do any tests anymore bcuz I've removed almost everything related to Java here. I'll have to setup me again

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question, especially after accepting an answer. It makes it meaningless for other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are concerned with doesn't really exist. Since `Paint` is an immutable class (which is a good design choice for a number of reasons), the correct way to update the color of something in JavaFX is to create a new `Paint` instance and set it as a property where needed. Previously-used instances which no longer have references to them will be cleaned up - efficiently - by the garbage collector at some point in the future.

Here is a simple demo which creates new `Paint` instances every time the scene is rendered (also new `Background` and `BackgroundFill` instances). It prints warnings if the frame rendering takes more than 25ms (an arbitrary threshold). On my system, it warns for the first couple of frames, and sometimes warns when the window is hidden and completely reshown.

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class UpdateColorContinuously extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        root.setMinSize(600, 600);

        new AnimationTimer() {

            private long start = -1 ;
            private long lastUpdate ;

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                if (start < 0) {
                    start = now ;
                    lastUpdate = now ;
                }
                long elapsed = now - start ;
                double elapsedSeconds  = elapsed / 1_000_000_000.0 ;
                Color newColor = Color.hsb(elapsedSeconds * 5, 1.0, 1.0);
                BackgroundFill fill = new BackgroundFill(newColor, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY);
                Background bg = new Background(fill);
                root.setBackground(bg);

                if (now - lastUpdate > 25_000_000) {
                    System.err.println("Warning: frame rendering took "+ (now-lastUpdate)/1_000_000 + " ms");
                }

                lastUpdate = now ;
            }

        }.start();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

It's possible I haven't run this long enough for the GC to need to run; a conservative estimate of the amount of memory a `Paint` instance needs is 50 bytes, so you would need to create of the order of `10^7` such instances to use 500MB (a reasonably small amount of RAM on a modern desktop system, which would likely be equivalent to one GC sweep). So, ballpark figures, this would generate one GC sweep in two days.

Comment: Seriously speaking, I'm not trolling. I didn't say _"make `Color` mutable"_. When I meant that the `Color` object could be _deleted_ (cleaned) right after its usage, I said about the compiler doing it. Under the hood, it'd be an optimization. It's possible in the code context (e.g., by watching how the instance is passed and how is used next), but the compiler may not be doing this actually.

Comment: Thanks for the throughout help. I still hate these JavaSE/JavaFX non-sense limitations... Well, I'll use it anyways :-)

Comment: @Hand1Cloud They aren't nonsense though. These design decisions are made by experts with decades of experience who carefully consider subtleties of design that are beyond things either you or I have the experience to consider. Not being able to directly delete objects is a fundamental aspect of the JVM: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21732826/is-it-possible-to-explicitly-free-memory-with-jvm-bytecode. Having `setRed(...)` methods in `Color` would make it mutable, which is a bad design. Creating objects and letting the GC remove them does not cause a performance issue in a modern JVM.

Comment: @Hand1Cloud See https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp02183/index.html and https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp01274/index.html for the last two points.